# How do I pull data from my MySQL database to pre populate a form on page load?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, populate

I have a site where users can register and then login with their registration information which takes them to a page with a form on it and I want to be able to pre populate certain parts of the form with data from when they registered/logged in.

I assumed since the login function uses session data that I could locate their email address and identify the row by said email address and then pull the data in the fields associated with that row. I can't find an example of how this works.

Once I am able to pull the data and populate the fields, the goal is to have 2 buttons; one to save and update the database so the user can return and finish the form later and the other button becomes active once all the fields are filled in and then submits the data to be printed on a confirmation page and also adds a value to the database field indicating that the form has been completed so when the user logs back in they will see that the form has been completed and is no longer able to be submitted.

I tried to populate one of the fields as a test by adding a value string to it but I cant seem to find an example anywhere to show how this works. Here is my form:

```
<div style="float:left;  width:450px;">
```

```
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;">SET PART #</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;">INSTALL DATE</div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">1.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part1" value="<?php echo $_GET['first_name'];?>"> </div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part1-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">2.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part2"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part2-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">3.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part3"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part3-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">4.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part4"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part4-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">5.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part5"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part5-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">6.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part6"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part6-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">7.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part7"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part7-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">8.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part8"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part8-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">9.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part9"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part9-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">10.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part10"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part10-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input class="send" id="register" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"></div>
</form>



</div>
```

Update:

I tried this method:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION)){
$userEmail=$_SESSION['email'];
$userData = fetch_assoc(query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '$userEmail'"));
}

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database'); //TODO: your connection here
function query($sql) {
 return mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
function fetch_assoc($query) {
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}

?>
```

and added this value to one of the form inputs:

```
value="<?= $userData['first_name'] ?>">
```

and am now getting 2 errors:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on this line:

```
return mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

and the other error:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on this line:

```
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Can you please show any PHP code you have written so far? I mean there is lots of ways of doing this, but it would be nice to see what you have tried so far... There are tons of tutorials on the internet to do everything you asked.

Comment: I had tried something like this with the PHP code in the header

    <?php

  include('Connections/loginENG.php'); 

  $data = "SELECT * FROM login where email = email";

  $query = mysql_query($data);
  
  $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  
  
?>

Comment: And what was the result..? What was wrong? Any errors?

Comment: Nothing at all happened actually. I tried a different method and added my results to the post. @Crembo

Comment: Do you have any MySQL server set up? If so, do you have any table with data in them? I'll update my answer when you answer that, I'll give a working code snippet..

Comment: Yes, I have created a registration page that inserts data into a table in my database and I have a login page that uses the Unique email address to log the user in to grant access to my page where the form resides. I created a test registered user and am trying to pull info from that into my form. @Crembo

Comment: I've edited my answer, trying working with that, see if you get any further. Also, make sure you have the PDO extension enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a MySQL database setup and filled with data, I'd recommend reading about PHP PDO:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

More specifically have a look at how to connect to your database:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

And after you have your connection setup, querying your database for information:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Especially look at Example #3.

Example for getting your user:

```
$user = <INSERT USER>;
$pass = <INSERT PASS>;
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<DATABASE NAME>', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = :userEmail");
$stmt->bindParam(':userEmail', $userEmail);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // now you can get your user details, for example, $user['username'] or however you have it set up in your database
}
```

Comment: I am completely new to PDO so some of this is a bit confusing. I took your example, wrapped it in <?php ?> tags and placed it before my html, I added my username, password and database name which connects no problem. I tried to pull the 'first_name' value with this in one of my form inputs:

value="<?= $user['first_name'] ?>">

and nothing is happening. Do I need to change :userEmail to something else? Like 'MM_Username' ? Should the $user in my value string be $userEmail? @Crembo

Comment: Try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); to better see what the error is. Also, :userEmail is whatever you set it to be in the next line. Also, try putting echo $user['first_name'] after $user = $stmt->fetch...

Comment: I tried to bind ':userEmail'to $email because the email field is the unique field that indicates the user and which row to pull data from. Is that correct? I added the error reporting and it spit out the number 22519. I added: echo $user['first_name']; after: $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); I also took out the second ")" after ASSOC)) because it was giving me a syntax error. I still cant get the input value to populate. @Crembo

Comment: I think I figured it out. I switched:

$stmt->bindParam(':userEmail', $userEmail);

with this:

$stmt->bindParam(':userEmail', $_SESSION['MM_Username']);

and was able to pull the data. I think this solves it. Thank you so much! @Crembo

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that should work. Glad I could be of help! Tell me if there is something unclear or other issues :)

Answer (score 0):

This couldn't be added at comments.

To answer your session part for data.

in your login code:

```
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email']; //make sure not to assign any weird characters.. (SQL-INJECTION)
```

and for getting your data:

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
$userEmail=$_SESSION['email'];
echo $userEmail;
//and for selecting ofc you would use the value..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to use a field (or fields) as primary key in your database. You mention that you could use the email field to do this, but check that the field is set as unique.

Then you can capture the session value of email and fetch the database for the rest of the data:

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
 $userEmail=$_SESSION['email'];
 $userData = fetch_assoc(query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email = '$userEmail'"));
}
```

Note that you should define `fetch_assoc`and `query`methods depending on your way to connect to the database. Something like:

```
global $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database'); //TODO: your connection here
function query($sql) {
 return mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
function fetch_assoc($query) {
 return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

Once you have that, you add in each input the corresponding value:

```
<input type="text" id="part2" value="<?= $userData['lastName'] ?>"/>
```

And so on.

Also, consider using classes instead of repeating code in styles.

Comment: I tried your method but I keep getting an error when defining the fetch_assoc and query. I get this: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given.

Comment: First of all the function "query" doesn't even have access to $link so it's going to fail to execute as $link isn't defined in that scope. Secondly, what's the point of wrapping mysqli_fetch_assoc in a function which only removes the "mysqli" prefix? Finally, I'd recommend using PDO as it's much more rigorous.

Comment: How are you able to access `$link` in the query() function? - You should include` $link` via `global $link;` to the function before you're using it.

Comment: Sorry I missed the global tag, now fixed.

@Crembo the only point is to make it shorter as this method is going to be called a lot of times. As for PDO vs Mysqli, even though first is possibly better, the latter is easier to learn from someone who has just started and doesn't understand objects just yet.